# .Less dynamically change text color based on parent's background-color

Tags: less

Let's say I have this layout:

```
<div id="parent">
    <p class="content">Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

I want to change the color of .content depending on weather the #parent background color is white or black. If it's white, then set the text color for .content to black and vice versa.